# Getting current stage GraphicsDevice in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt, javafx-2

Is it possible to get GraphicsDevice of current JavaFX stage?

I know that you are able to get current screen via Screen.getScreensForRectangle method, but I really need GraphicsDevice instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Screen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) method, e.g. one of the `getScreensForRectangle()`, to find the `screen` of interest. In the [`GraphicsEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) obtained from `getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()`, iterate though each [`GraphicsConfiguration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html) of each [`GraphicsDevice`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) to find those devices whose bounds intersect the bounds obtained from `screen.getBounds()`. There may be more than one. A typical iteration scheme is shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html).